# JMS Connection is closed with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, jms, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I use Spring Boot 1.2.3-RELEASE with ActiveMQ 5.11.1.

I have configured JMS with the following:

```
spring:
  activemq:
    inMemory: false
    broker-url: tcp://localhost:61616?wireFormat.maxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=30000
```

And I send messages like this:

```
    jmsTemplate.send(Queues.BULK_LOAD_BYINSERT_FILE, new MessageCreator() {
        @Override
        public Message createMessage(javax.jms.Session session) throws JMSException {
            log.info("******** SEND BULK_LOAD_BYINSERT: {}", file.getName());
            return session.createObjectMessage(file);
        }
    });
```

When I send messages once in a while I will get the following ERROR. I have no idea how I could avoid this problem, and how I could detect where is the connection closed. Would anyone have an suggestion how I could proceed to avoid this?

Thanks for your help.

```
    2015-05-18 17:48:19.305 ERROR 27713 --- [enerContainer-1] c.b.services.BulkLoaderServices     : Problem while bulkLoading XXX.201211.df5e480c604896098447873e1436a75e

org.springframework.jms.IllegalStateException: The Session is closed; nested exception is javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The Session is closed
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:279)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:169)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:496)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:579)
    at com.bulkLoader.services.BulkLoaderServices.dataLoaded(BulkLoaderServices.java:155)
    at com.bulkLoader.services.BulkLoaderServices.bulkLoad(BulkLoaderServices.java:116)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:185)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:674)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:634)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:605)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:308)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:226)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1144)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1136)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1033)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The Session is closed
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.checkClosed(ActiveMQSession.java:767)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.createQueue(ActiveMQSession.java:1265)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver.resolveQueue(DynamicDestinationResolver.java:84)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver.resolveDestinationName(DynamicDestinationResolver.java:58)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JmsDestinationAccessor.resolveDestinationName(JmsDestinationAccessor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.access$200(JmsTemplate.java:90)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$4.doInJms(JmsTemplate.java:582)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:493)
    ... 19 common frames omitted

2015-05-18 17:48:19.326 ERROR 27713 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Application exception overridden by rollback exception

org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void com.bulkLoader.services.BulkLoaderServices.bulkLoad(java.io.File)' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jms.IllegalStateException: The Session is closed; nested exception is javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The Session is closed
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:98)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:674)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:634)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:605)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:308)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:226)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1144)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1136)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1033)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.jms.IllegalStateException: The Session is closed; nested exception is javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The Session is closed
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:279)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:169)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:496)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:579)
    at com.bulkLoader.services.BulkLoaderServices.submitErrorProblem(BulkLoaderServices.java:164)
    at com.bulkLoader.services.BulkLoaderServices.bulkLoad(BulkLoaderServices.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:185)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:90)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The Session is closed
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.checkClosed(ActiveMQSession.java:767)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.createQueue(ActiveMQSession.java:1265)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver.resolveQueue(DynamicDestinationResolver.java:84)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver.resolveDestinationName(DynamicDestinationResolver.java:58)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JmsDestinationAccessor.resolveDestinationName(JmsDestinationAccessor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.access$200(JmsTemplate.java:90)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$4.doInJms(JmsTemplate.java:582)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:493)
    ... 19 common frames omitted

2015-05-18 17:48:19.327  WARN 27713 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.

javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The Session is closed
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.checkClosed(ActiveMQSession.java:767)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.getTransacted(ActiveMQSession.java:532)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.rollbackOnExceptionIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:747)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:612)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:308)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:226)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1144)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1136)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1033)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: are you sure your queue is up? I had the same error when I noticed up in the log that my JMX connector failed to start due to another issue.

Comment: Could you post your JMSTemplate bean config - I use JMSTemplate and havent seen this issue.

Comment: I use the JmsTemplate generated by Spring Boot. With Spring Boot 1.2.4-RELEASE I do not have the problem anymore.